# getopt() behaviour is unusual

Tags: c, getopt

`getopt()` is not behaving as I expect for short options.

eg: Invoking the below program with a missing parameter:

Valid Case: `testopt -d dir -a action -b build`

Error Case: `testopt -d -a action -b build`

This did not throw any error as I was expecting an error message operand missing for `-d`

- Is this a known bug?
- If so, is there any standard fix available?

My code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
/* testopt.c                       */
/* Test program for testing getopt */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int chr;
    while ( ( chr = getopt(argc, argv, ":d:a:b:") ) != -1 )
    {
            switch(chr)
            {
                    case 'a':
                            printf("Got a...\n");
                            break;
                    case 'b':
                            printf("Got b...\n");
                            break;
                    case 'd':
                            printf("Got d...\n");
                            break;
                    case ':':
                            printf("Missing operand for %c\n", optopt);
                            break;
                    case '?':
                            printf("Unknown option %c\n", optopt);
                            break;
            }
    }
    printf("execution over\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getopt()` thinks `-a` is an argument for `-d`, not an option.

Try `testopt -a action -b build -d` - it should complain about missing argument.

You need to check for `-d` option (and all other options) that `optarg` has valid value - the one without dash in the beginning.

Comment: The invocation is not under the control of the program and so I think verifying whether the first character is "-" is a solution as you said.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt), you should start your option string with a colon in order to make `getopt()` return `':'` to indicate missing argument. The default seems to be returning `'?'`.

Comment: I modified with that option but it is behaving the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine for me, using gcc 3.4.5 on Red Hat:

```
$ ./a.out -d test
Got d...
execution over

$ ./a.out -d
Missing operand for d
execution over
```

What's your environment?

**UPDATE**: OK, qrdl is spot on. How come getopt() works that way?